# Jmeter How to run a endpoint with 10 users(one at a time) then start another endpoint with 10 users(one at a time) and so on

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Jmeter How to run an endpoint with 10 users(one at a time) then start another endpoint with 10 users(one at a time) and so on. So basically only one call is running at a time. Also i want to have the average of 10 users per endpoint. This is how i have structured it. Not sure if this is the best way to do it.

[image]

I have created Journey Steps where I have my calls. Then i have created Setup for authentication token(using module controller method) and then the two endpoints(10 calls per endpoint). I want to know if they will be running one at a time? Also i want to have the average of 10 users per endpoint. They are running without any error just not sure if they run all at once or seprately

Answer (score 1):

with this setting they should run one at a time, when a response is received, another request is triggered. If you want to run the two thread groups sequentially, there is an option that allows you to do that in the test plan settings.[image: option]

Answer (score -1):

1. You don't need to copy and paste 10 requests, it's better to parameterize the request using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
2. Once you do this you will be able to use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) to kick off 10 requests at exactly the same moment.

Suggested test plan structure:

[image]

Comment: i want to run 10 requests not at the exactly same time. I want to run one at a time and when it finished the 10 request then move to the next thread

Comment: would you be able to tell how can i run 10 requests one by one instead of all together. thank you in advance